# Angular2 Route Components not rendering variable bindings on load

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

1. When first entering the application, the template binding details are properly shown.
2. However, when navigating the links the bindings are loaded but not rendered until you click the link a second time.  It looks like it refreshes and the template bindings are then properly shown.
3. Clicking a link a third time will now invoke the route.  This issue also seems to cause router links to not be rendered as anchors, but they are clickable.

I am targeting *Angular-2.0.0.beta-1*.

An example can be found here: [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JG3Bsj8A2DBb2no1eA1W?p=preview)

- The first link, "Dashboard" shows a list of numbers.
- The second link, "Welcome" shows lorem ipsum.

**When the content is not shown, the following markup appears:**

```html
<ul>
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</ul>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

***UPDATE***
Per @SnareChops I tried *Beta.2*,*Beta.0*,*Alpha.55* and the issue is still occurring.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

***Update 2***
Replaced the scripts with a different CDN.  Plnkr is now working.  Thank you @SnareChops

```html
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/router.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Angular2@2.0.0-beta.1 has known issues, I would recommend updating to beta 2 or downgrading to beta 0.

Comment: @SnareChops may i know whats the issue with the angular2@2.0.0-beta.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

We changed the CDN from cdnjs.cloudflare.com to code.angularjs.org and now it seems to work.